# Unable to use Laravel's s3 driver after running composer update

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5.1

I ran a `composer update` and ever since, if I try do a s3 bucket call it fails `500` with no stack trace. I am using hhvm `-v 3.8.1` and laravel `-v 5.1`

My s3 call:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->exists('file.txt')
```

Not quite sure what information to give. There is just no stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Was due to hhvm `-v 3.8` not being compatible with guzzle `-v 6` so I updated my hhvm to `3.10.1`